# Linux find -exec permission denied

Tags: linux, shell, command, redhat, permission-denied

I wrote a shell script iterating through files and ordering their contents and saving the new order back to the file.

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in "$@"; do
    sort $i -k2 -o $i
done
```

The files to be sorted are chosen with the `find` command like so:

```
find . -regex '<myregex>' -exec ./mysort.sh {} +
```

I wrote the script and tried it out one machine as a specific user and then copied it over to another machine using root privileges. So now the files has `chown root:root` as have all the files I wand to search through.

So now the files to be sorted are located in the same folder as the mysort.sh and when I try to execute the find with -exec i get

`find: './mysort.sh': Permission denied`

I tried moving the script to a subfolder and executing the command with `-exec ./folder/mysort.sh` or moving it to a higher level folder and executing it with `-exec ../mysort.sh`. I always get different variations of Permission denied errors.

Comment: Does the script have permission to execute? `ls -l mysort.sh`

Comment: yes, it has `-rwxrwxr-x`

Comment: Have you used `noexec` flag when mounting this filesystem?

Comment: I did not mount the filesystem myself but just checked and it actually was mounted with noexec! Thanks so much! Do you want to post this as an answer maybe including how to check? Otherwise I will answer it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the filesystem was mounted with `noexec` flag.

But you can still run your script via `bash`:

```
bash /path/to/mysort.sh
```